# comparison operator in count() is not working

Tags: sql-server, operator

The query (`SELECT 15 > 14 FROM Duel`) Working in MySql, but when I tried in MS-SQL Server getting following error:

> SQL Error(102): Incorrect syntax near '>'

I have a requirement where I want to see if at least 1 record exist return 1 or else 0

```
SELECT count(emp.name) > 0
        FROM ****
        WHERE *** IN (***)
```

Check the [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=348709a562ad02cbe88abf01a37229f1)

Comment: SQL Server does not have the equivalent of table Duel. No FROM clause is required in T-SQL. Nor does it have a Boolean data type, which `15 > 14` would return. Nor does your query have columns named `[15]` or `[14]`. Try using `EXISTS()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to return a 1 or 0 based on a condition, [see example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f13c04ccfd8a93d3d50da9a4e867564):

```
SELECT IIF(COUNT(EmpID) > 0, 1, 0) AS [RecordsExist]
FROM Employee
WHERE EmpName IN ('Dave', 'Carol')
```

Returns 1 if any rows in the Employee table exist with an EmpName value of 'Dave' or 'Carol'

Comment: Nice. It works fine

Comment: @PSatishPatro, just FYI, since you working on multiple platforms (mySQL and MS-SQL), consider `IIF` only applicable in SQL-SERVER 2012+, but `CASE` works in all SQL platforms

Comment: yeah. For now I am working only on SQL Server, was just checking if it works in MySQL. But, as you said needs to consider if db changes to MySQL. Thanks

Comment: Just note that this doesn't return a Boolean, since there are no such Boolean types in SQL server. It returns an int (or perhaps smallint or tinyint).

Answer (score 1):

> I have a requirement where I want to see if at least 1 record exist return 1 or else 0

You can do that with following query in MS-SQL ([db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=573d1f1fd6e883e6a2684f2baa9f91c7))

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count (*) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM new_table_name
```

Not sure how mySQL treats this `SELECT 15 > 14 FROM Duel`, but in MS-SQL it's not complete statement (even columns exists with the name 15 and 14), operators (`=`, `<>`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `LIKE`, `IN`, `NOT IN`) usually used in `WHERE` and `ON` clauses. When it used in `SELECT` clause it must complete the Boolean logic (`CASE`, `IIF`).

Comment: why someone gives downvote to a working solution?

Comment: @PSatishPatro, probably for `count (*) > 1` which is corrected already to `count (*) >= 1`. If not that one, i would welcome comments.

Comment: ok, may be. but other should telll the error